# Using a PC as a router with a Verizon modem

Tags: networking, internet, modem

I currently live in the boondocks where the only internet we can receive is through Verizon's wireless card. This means that only one user can be on the internet at a time through an USB modem connection. However I was wondering if there was a way to work around this.

Is there a possibility to set up a network in which the verizon modem is connected to the internet through a Windows 7 PC and setting up that PC to act as a router. In other words, could I connect to my PC with another PC or iPod touch to gain internet access to where multiple users can access the internet?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're looking for is what Microsoft calls [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing).  Note that not all editions of Windows 7 support it–in particular, Starter (the netbook version) does not–but for those that do, this is a simple and straightforward way to share the connection with other users on your network.

Also be aware that not all ISPs permit the usage of this feature in their ToS.

Comment: From my understanding Windows ICS is the equivalent of NATing, and if you have Windows starter, either upgrade or switch to Linux, as starter is good for next-to-nothing. But yes it is possible, I have a very similar setup at my house with my cell phone as the ISP link to my laptop being a router.

Comment: And @BMDan is correct as it may violate your ToS, I am not sure since you are using Verizon... but theoretically if it is NATing, Verizon would know no different of to where the traffic is originating from other than that laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could have the laptop or whatever create an ad-hoc network, and then share the connection.

Comment: This does not work on all windows 7 hardware combinations.

Comment: I've broadcasted an ad-hoc network without issue before. Don't see how its different from connecting to a regular wifi.

Comment: Not all drivers will let this work properly

Comment: So you are saying they can see it as an ad-hoc network, and connect to it as if it was a stardard wifi network, but they can't get internet through it? example?

Comment: some drivers will not let the ICS wizard to configure the private interface.

Answer (score 0):

try Virtual Router - [Wifi Hot Spot for Windows 7 / 2008 R2](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) Of course verizon may not be pleased with the setup