# Using a PC as a router with a Verizon modem

Tags: windows-7, internet, modem

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a PC as a router with a Verizon modem](https://superuser.com/questions/291286/using-a-pc-as-a-router-with-a-verizon-modem)

I currently live in the boondocks where the only internet we can receive is through Verizon's wireless card. This means that only one user can be on the internet at a time through a USB modem connection. However I was wondering if there was a way to work around this.

Is there a possibility to set up a network in which the verizon modem is connected to the internet through a Windows 7 PC and setting up that PC to act as a router. In other words, could I connect to my PC with another PC or Ipod touch to gain internet access to where multiple users can access the internet?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you're looking for is what Microsoft calls [Internet Connection Sharing](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing).  Note that not all editions of Windows 7 support it–in particular, Starter (the netbook version) does not–but for those that do, this is a simple and straightforward way to share the connection with other users on your network.

Also be aware that not all ISPs permit the usage of this feature in their ToS.

Answer (score 0):

try [Virtual Router - Wifi Hot Spot for Windows 7 / 2008 R2](http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/) Of course verizon may not be pleased with the setup

Answer (score 0):

Look at the properties dialog for your network adapter. On there, you will find a 'Sharing' tab that allows you to do this. I've never attempted to do this, as personally, I'd buy a cheap home router, or find an old PC and install Linux, but to answer your question, yes you can do what you want with Windows 7.